# Gitlab CI - Build Docker Image With Shared Runner (cannot connect to Docker Daemon)

Tags: docker, gitlab

I am currently using Gitlab Shared Runners to build and deploy my project (at least I'm trying too !).

I have the gitlab-ci.yml below :

```
image: java:8-jdk

stages:
  - build
  - package

before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle
  - docker info

cache:
  paths:
    - .gradle/wrapper
    - .gradle/caches
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/libs/*.jar
    expire_in: 1 week
  only:
    - master

docker-build:
  image: docker:stable
  services:
   - docker:dind
  stage: package
  script:
    docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/my-project .
    docker push registry.gitlab.com/my-project

after_script:
  - echo "End CI"
```

First, build stage is doing great, but there is a problem with the second stage when I'm trying to build and push my docker image.

I get this log :

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

It seems that Gitlab is using a shared runner that can't build a docker image, but I don't know how I can change that. I cannot change the configuration of my runner, because I'm using shared runners. I also tried to put some tags to my second stages, in hope that a more suitable runner would have to take care of my job, but I'm still getting this error.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you need to set `DOCKER_HOST` to connect to the DinD running in another container:

```
docker-build:
  image: docker:stable
  services:
   - docker:dind
  stage: package
  script:
    - export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker:2375/
    - docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/my-project .
    - docker push registry.gitlab.com/my-project
```

Comment: Thank you for your help ! I tried your solution and it seems to work : job is now building, but I'm still getting an error when it's trying to push the image on my repository. The push refers to repository [registry.gitlab.com/XXXXX/my-project]
a7c4fef80584: Preparing
269299191353: Preparing
0daf3549c2ef: Preparing
e0974bfaea82: Preparing
denied: access forbidden
Do you have an idea ? Anyway, your suggestion worked, thank you !

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot to login to my docker registry, using this line :  - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY

Comment: `DOCKER_HOST` sets the [`host`](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runnersdocker-section) variable in the runner's configuration. You very possibly don't know this variable.

Answer (score 1):

If your shared [runner executor is of type `docker`](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/) you may try this setup :

```
stages:
  - build
  - package

before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle
  - docker info

cache:
  paths:
    - .gradle/wrapper
    - .gradle/caches
build:
  image: java:8-jdk
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/libs/*.jar
    expire_in: 1 week
  only:
    - master

docker-build:
  stage: package
  script:
    docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/my-project .
    docker push registry.gitlab.com/my-project

after_script:
  - echo "End CI"
```

Comment: Your `docker info` won't even run, because gitlab's shared runners doesn't have it. You have to use a docker image.

Answer (score 1):

Even we have faced the same problem in our org. We found that there is a long standing issue with the docker in docker area for gitlab which can be tracked in these issues [#3612](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/3612#note_130459623), [#2408](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/2408) and [#2890](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/2890) as well.

We have found that in our case using docker binding was much suitable for our usecase than the docker-in-docker one. so, we used the solution in their [official page](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-socket-binding).

I know this has been already answered but this may help some one who have a similar usecase :)